# Access escaped JSON in mySql Query

Tags: mysql, json

I'm running a mySQL query like this:

```
select * 
from resError
where errorDescription like '%ENSURE NAME DOB AND GENDER EXIST IN SSR DOCS%'
```

This returns results like:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id        | errorDescription                           |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
| 1         | {\r\n  \"details\": \"INVALID - ENSURE.... |   
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

The full text of the `errorDescription` field is an escaped json object like this:

{\r\n  \"details\": \"INVALID - ENSURE NAME DOB AND GENDER EXIST IN SSR DOCS FOR US   \",\r\n  \"session\": {\r\n    \"flightType\": \"Worldspan\",\r\n    \"pt\": \"hf\",\r\n    \"fl\": \"PDX\",\r\n    \"tl\": \"PHX\",\r\n    \"xmlConnectionId\": \"9\",\r\n    \"FlightDetails\": {\r\n      \"IssuingCarrierCode\": \"US\",\r\n      \"RestrictedTicket\": \"1\",\r\n    },\r\n    \"reservationId\": 21614475,\r\n    \"PNR\": \"LQ8O7M\"\r\n  }\r\n}

**There are more values that I have left out, those listed are the only ones I care about**

The un-escaped JSON object would look like this

```
{
  "details": "INVALID - ENSURE NAME DOB AND GENDER EXIST IN SSR DOCS FOR US",
  "session": {
    "flightType": "Worldspan",
    "pt": "hf",
    "fl": "PDX",
    "tl": "PHX",
    "xmlConnId": "9",
    "FlightDetails": {
      "IssuingCarrierCode": "US",
      "RestrictedTicket": "1",
    },
    "resId": 2161,
    "PNR": "LQ8RRM"
  }
}
```

How can I access the values in the text of the errorDescription field so as to end up with results like the below?

```
+----+-----------+----+-----+-----+-----------+--------------------+------------------+--------+
| id | flightType| pt | fl  | tl  | xmlConnId | IssuingCarrierCode | RestrictedTicket |   PNR  |
+----+-----------+----+-----+-----+-----------+--------------------+------------------+--------+
| 1  | Worldspan | hf | PDX | PHX |    9      |         US         |        1         | LQ8RRM |
+----+-----------+----+-----+-----+-----------+--------------------+------------------+--------+
```

I would love to normalize the stored data, unfortunately, that is not an option. My department does not have write access to this table and the department that owns it wants it to stay the way it is. This is not a query that I will ever need to run again so performance is not a primary concern.

This is the mySQL version I am working with:

[image]

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: @JorgeCampos updated above, thank you

Comment: Unfortunately as your current version does not have support to JSON features will will have to create a function to break the json string and return it as a record. Fortunatelly you can use a udf function as [common_schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) take a look and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but someone might be looking for an answer.

You could run an update statement on all the json-columns with the JSON_UNQUOTE function. This will make the columns into clean json, and then you can use the built-in JSON_* functions in mysql.

Also, if you have access to this part of the application, check how the data is inserted. The quotes might not be needed and the insert logic should/could be changed to not include the quotes.